# Read a file .txt C++

Tags: c++, compare, symbols

How should I read lines with `space`s from a `file.txt` and record it in my `vector`?
I have a line that consists of many words ,but my loop doesn't see that and read them one by one and print in that way:

For example,I have a string in a file:

```
Hello, my friends,how are you?

Hello,James, we are fine.
```

And in my console, I see:

```
Hello,
my
friends
....
fine
```

This my loop:

```
while(rRecord»str)
{
    lines.push_back(str);
}
```

And my function that prints my words:

```
void printRecord(int& numStr,struct winsize w,std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{

for (int i = numStr; i < numStr + w.winsize::ws_row-1; i++)
{

   if (i>=lines.size())
   break;
   else
   std::cout « lines[i] « std::endl;

}

    numStr += w.winsize::ws_row;
}
```

Comment: What about using `std::getline()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read line-by-line, use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), like this:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {
    lineVector.push_back(std::move(line));
}
```

The `std::move` means that when the `vector` creates the new element, it can "steal" the internal buffer from `line`, meaning `line` will now be an empty string, but saves an extra allocation+copy.

---

Be aware that mixing `getline` with `>>` is usually not a good idea, because `>>` will leave any trailing whitespace, including a newline, in the stream, meaning you get unexpected results the next time you try to `getline`.

Comment: Thanks for answer , try to use it

Comment: The `std::move` call looks a lot like premature optimisation.